# phonegap/cordova twitter login ios

Tags: ios, cordova, twitter

i am using sttwiter sdk for twitter login in phonegap.

This method note return -

```
- (void)setOAuthToken:(NSString *)token oauthVerifier:(NSString *)verifier  
{
  [_twitter postAccessTokenRequestWithPIN:verifier successBlock:^(NSString *oauthToken, NSString *oauthTokenSecret, NSString *userID, NSString *screenName)
     {
        NSLog(@"-- screenName: %@", screenName);
 }
    errorBlock:^(NSError *error)
     {

       // _loginStatusLabel.text = [error localizedDescription];
        NSLog(@"-- %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];

}
```

Comment: You need much more information for anyone to help you.  What is happening exactly?  Are you getting an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: i have make phonegap in 3.0 ver for ios. then implement sttwiter sdk for twitter login. i have send to class code.

Comment: Please just fix your question with whatever information you have.